# Доступ к cookies другого сайта

Tags: javascript

Не знаю, или правильно написал вопрос в заголовке. Вообще вопрос такой.
Есть, например виджет коминтариев фб, его можно установить на свой сайт. При заходе, он сразу покажет активного пользователя фейсбук в этом браузере(если он есть). Как это возможно? Этот виджет на стороннем сайте имеет достут к сессии сайта фейсбук или как?

Comment: добавь в вопрос ссылку на виджет

Comment: наверное, чтобы подключить этот виджет, нужно скрипт установить какой-нибудь. Вот он все и отслеживает

Comment: два варианта: виджет шлет запрос на facebook, в этом случае куки отправляются на свой домен, и в полученном ответе вся информация для отображения, либо iframe в котором опять же facebook

Comment: Проверил. Это правда фрейм. Спасибо

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie#а-если-очень-надо

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего это просто iframe. В любой iframe можно зайти через обычные узлы JavaScript. Дело в том, что для https соединения наверняка реализована httpOnly Cookie, которую вы не сможете получить через JavaScript. Остальные cookie считаются почти бесполезными.